# JNDI lookup on TomEE

Tags: ejb, jndi, apache-tomee

Hi have a Web project and a EJB project running on the same TomEE sever.

I have deployed the EJB project in the apps folder of the TomEE server and can see the EJB's are starting when the server starts.

```
INFO: Jndi(name=DefaultRegistrationProcess) --> Ejb(deployment-id=DefaultRegistrationProcess)
```

Below is one of the `@Stateless` beans in the EJB project

```
@Stateless(name = "DefaultRegistrationProcess")
public class DefaultRegistrationProcess implements RegistrationProcess {

    @Override
    public void process(Registration registration) {
        System.out.println("Hello from Default registration process!");
    }

}
```

From the Web project I want to do a JNDI Lookup to the DefaultRegistrationProcess bean.

Packaging the EJB with the Web project via maven I can do the JNDI Lookup using the following code.

```
new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/DefaultRegistrationProcess");
```

When trying to do the same call when the EJB is deploy separately I get

```
Exception occured: Name "module/DefaultRegistrationProcess" not found.
```

I have looked through the http://tomee.apache.org/documentation.html site and tried some examples but I'm still getting the error.

How can I do a local JNDI Lookup from within the Web project to the EJB when it is deployed on the same TomEE server?

Comment: can you provide some info about the version of the server you are using and which Java EE Spec are you following?

Comment: I'm using Apache-tomee-1.7.1-plus. The following is what I tried, http://tomee.apache.org/basics---getting-things.html http://tomee.apache.org/lookup-of-other-ejbs-example.html

Comment: Could you please provide your JNDI tree?

Comment: Hi Aribeiro, not sure what you mean by JNDI tree.

Comment: You've already solved it but the JNDI tree is the hierarchical directory structure of all services that are available for discovery and/or being looked up. Normally, you can access it via administration console of your application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add @Remote to my business interface which my `DefaultRegistrationProcess` class implement.

```
@Remote
public interface RegistrationProcess {

    public void process(Registration registration);

}
```

After that I could make a JNDI lookup using the `LocalInitialContextFactory`  property and the JNDI name of `DefaultRegistrationProcessRemote`.

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory");
 new InitialContext(p).lookup("DefaultRegistrationProcessRemote");
```

Comment: Just as a side note, use `org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory` instead of `org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory`, the later is `@Deprecated`